# consul connect sidecar with spring boot microservices

Tags: consul, sidecar

I'm very new to Consul connect sidecars.
Below is my setup
I have a consul server with is running at 8500 port.
I have 2 spring based microservices A & B with dynamic ports server.port=0. Both the services are got discovered by consul.
consul-connect is enabled in server.

After register the services to Consul, when I add intention to deny from service A to Service B, Still I'm able to call service B from service A 'http://A/contxt/...

Not if anything I need to do here. I don't find any low level document for this.

Can some one help me setup the sidecars for my services and how I can enable intentions?